# iCloud allows access to files via direct link without authentication!

Tags: icloud, bug, file-sharing

I've been testing sharing files from iCloud when I accidentally stumbled onto this bug.

Steps to Repro:

- In Firefox preferences, set "Portable Document Format" download action to *always ask*.

> [image]

- Log into iCloud.com and tap on a PDF file's name (Blue URL) to download it but, instead of *saving* it, Select *Open with  other..*  and choose Firefox.app in the app list.
- The file will display right in the browser as expected. Now, copy the link in the address bar: `https://cvws.icloud-content.com/B/[loooong_string]` and
  take that link to a different browser altogether with no iCloud login.

The file is still openly accessible. To anyone with that link!

Yes, granted it's not the type of a link to be easily guessed but the file was NOT intentionally shared or made available via a link and NO authentication was needed to access it.

Is this behavior by design? Gaining access to this link appears to be posing a huge security risk, isn't it?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this.. I opened a numbers file in Safari.. It had URL like https://www.icloud.com/numbers/<The-key> and I opened the URL in private mode and it asked for password. Where did you get this cvws link ?

Comment: @ankii Thanks for looking into this... I'm in Firefox and yes, the **https://cvws.icloud-content.com/...** is the link I get in the address bar when I double-click an image (jpg in my case) as described above.

Comment: @ankii ...also note that this pertains to **iCloud Drive > Desktop & Documents Folders** content, not native Apple apps, such as Numbers (with those I do get the same link you've mentioned)

Comment: FB7389134 include this ID in case someone reports this.  https://feedbackassistant.apple.com.

Answer (score 2):

I filed a bug report.

Them:

> Can you please set up such a file (not shared) and then send us the link so that we can confirm we are able to access it despite your intent not to share?
>
> Thanks,

Me: Here's the link.

Me, later: The link shows "gone" after some time. Here's another.

Them:

> This is by design. The link URL will expire.
>
> Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: The expiry of the link is actually pretty annoying, because if you want to send someone a file download link without the landing page or have a link you can `wget` at any time, it will not be possible to do so. You would have to host it yourself on a web server.