# iCloud Drive Issues with one file

Tags: icloud

I got a 185Gb Parallels Virtual Machine which iCloud has uploaded to iCloud Drive and removed off my Mac (thanks apple). When I try to Right Click on the file and select "Download Now" I get a "Not enough space error" although I have over 300Gb of space on my flash drive. If I try to drag the file from my iCloud Drive to an external SSD I get "The operation can't be completed because an unexpected error occurred (error code -1407)", the same error comes up if I try to move or copy the file to the external SSD (it has over 220Gb of space)

I've even tried to download the file from the iCloud Drive web portal on my Mac and on a PC with a number of different browsers. I get a .Zip file downloaded of around 3-5Gb in size which appears to be corrupt no matter which file I use to open up.

Currently the file sits there on my iCloud Drive with a cloud with an exclamation mark inside it (Sync error)

Any suggestions how to get my file back?

p.s. no I haven't a backup

Comment: What if you move other files off your Mac to the external SSD to free up even more space? Then turn off Optimize My Mac.

Comment: Also maybe this tool might be helpful? https://github.com/ezfe/iCloud-Manager/releases

Comment: There's another troubleshooting tool for iCloud storage [brctl](https://eclecticlight.co/2018/04/12/diagnosing-icloud-problems-using-brctl-sync-budgets-and-throttles/)

Comment: @Nic seems to be correct, have you tried turning off Optimise storage ? Other than that, I doubt that browsers are capable of handling that big a file. Use curl or wget to download it, you'll need some modifications to the command in case iCloud asks for password. Also, you'll need some tricks to get the link to the file. see this: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/372855/313842